# How to loop through an JSON object in Jquery to match a string then return a particular value?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Quite new to JQuery and having issues searching through a JSON object and returning a particular result. This the object I have:

```
"serviceProviderLocationList": [
        {
            "serviceProvider": {
                "value": "NBN"
            },
            "locationList": [
                {
                    "sourceSystemAddressId": null,
                    "serviceProvider": "NBN",
                    "locationId": "LOC000158748472",
                    "address": {
                        "subAddressNumber": "121",
                    },
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "serviceProvider": {
                "value": "Telstra"
            },
            "locationList": [
                {
                    "sourceSystemAddressId": null,
                    "locationId": "266292692",
                    "address": {
                        "subAddressNumber": null,
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    "sourceSystemAddressId": null,
                    "locationId": "427275955",
                    "address": {
                        "subAddressNumber": "LIFT",
                    },
                },
                {
                    "sourceSystemAddressId": null,
                    "locationId": "267743661",
                    "address": {
                        "subAddressNumber": "100",
                    },
                },
                {
                    "sourceSystemAddressId": null,
                    "locationId": "267743660",
                    "address": {
                        "subAddressNumber": "99",
                        },
                    },
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "serviceProvider": {
                "value": "AAPT"
            },
            "locationList": []
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to search the part of the object where:

serviceProviderLocationList.ServiceProvider.value == 'Telstra'

Then search through the relevant LocationList and if:

this.complexAddress.unit == locationList.address.subAddressNumber

Return the right Location ID.

For example if this.complexAddress.unit == '100', then it should return Location ID == 267743661

Or this.complexAddress.unit == 'null', then it would return Location ID == 266292692

This the code I'm using at the moment, to get the JSON object:

GetTelstraServiceID: function getTelstraServiceID( event )
{
    event.preventDefault();

```
    var data = {
        'address': this.complexAddress,
        'action': 'get_location_id'
    },

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: site_vars.ajaxurl,
        data: data
    })
    .done(function( response ) {



        var data = $.parseJSON( response ),
            locationID = data.serviceProviderLocationList[1].locationList[0].locationId;



        if ( typeof locationID !== 'undefined' ) {
            that.locationID = locationID;

        } else {
            alert('We couldn\'t find this address, sorry');
        }
    });
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *JSON object*. If it's JSON, it's a `string`. If it's an `object`, it's Javascript.

Comment: Also, your JSON is invalid.

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, why haven't you picked an answer yet? If not, why haven't you commented accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.filter()` to find the provider and locationID you're looking for.

```js
function getLocationId(data, provider, unit) {
  return data.filter(d => d.serviceProvider.value===provider)[0].locationList.filter(d => d.address.subAddressNumber === unit)[0].locationId;
}

const data = JSON.parse(`[{
    "serviceProvider": {
      "value": "NBN"
    },
    "locationList": [{
      "sourceSystemAddressId": null,
      "serviceProvider": "NBN",
      "locationId": "LOC000158748472",
      "address": {
        "subAddressNumber": "121"
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    "serviceProvider": {
      "value": "Telstra"
    },
    "locationList": [{
        "sourceSystemAddressId": null,
        "locationId": "266292692",
        "address": {
          "subAddressNumber": null
        }
      },
      {
        "sourceSystemAddressId": null,
        "locationId": "427275955",
        "address": {
          "subAddressNumber": "LIFT"
        }
      },
      {
        "sourceSystemAddressId": null,
        "locationId": "267743661",
        "address": {
          "subAddressNumber": "100"
        }
      },
      {
        "sourceSystemAddressId": null,
        "locationId": "267743660",
        "address": {
          "subAddressNumber": "99"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "serviceProvider": {
      "value": "AAPT"
    },
    "locationList": []
  }
]`)

console.log(getLocationId(data, 'Telstra', null))
console.log(getLocationId(data, 'Telstra', '100'))
```

The rest of your code example is incomplete, so I couldn't fully answer your question in my code.

Comment: Thanks a connexo! I’ll have a fiddle around and see what I come up with.

Comment: I have added the rest of your requirements. It is basically using `Array.prototype.filter()` twice.